# My JSQMessagesViewController is empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have implemented a `UIViewController` subclass where I display a UIView using a storyboard. The view is embedded in a `UITabViewController`. I have copied the demo and removed the parts that seem to be just for a demo (existing messages).

Currently there are UI issues with the keyboard (no display) and the "New Message" input field.
I wonder if perhaps they are behind the tab view controller, or if there's something I am missing.

Comment: Post your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stupidly failed to properly configure the view controller so an empty view controller without any code behind it was showing.